# Why is the adjoint a useful concept

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been reading my linear algebra book, and am now on the section about the adjoint of a linear operator, I get the definition provided and even think I understand the general proof of existence and uniqueness but can't for the life of me seem to understand why such a thing would be useful . I've looked other places but can't seem to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Typically an adjoint is a formalism in a lot of different situations, typically if A is adjoint to B then there is a relationship that looks kind of like this:

$$\left(Ax,y\right) = \left(x, By\right)$$

In linear operators, if you start with a vector-space $ f: V \rightarrow W $ such that there are a bilinear mappings $B_{V}:V \times V \rightarrow F $ and $B_{W}: W \times W \rightarrow F$ where F is some field, form and define an inverse map $ g: W \rightarrow V $ such that

$$B_{V}(v, g(w)) = B_{W}(f(v), w) \; \forall \: v \in V, w \in W $$

the fun thing that happens is that you get to now talk about transposes without having to deal with matrices, you just work with them in form of operators.